# jquery not post data in IE

Tags: php, jquery

i create one simple form in which i have one combobox when i am selecting any thing i put one function onchange event so its call.

then i send this data in one helper file through jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
function Searchwine(obj,str) {  
{queryString: ""+str+""}, function(data){           
    jQuery.post("http://www.site.com/search/helper/autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+str+""}, function(data){          
        if(data.length >0) {
jQuery('#windatano').html(data);
}
</script>
```

i am using this code for post data in autosuggest from through javascript and print replay of jquery in windatano `id`

--> its working fine in crome and ff and other all browser but in IE its not working

Can any help?
Thanks,

Comment: I hope you realize that `""+str+""` is concatenating two empty strings to the `str` variable... in other words, doing nothing that a simple `.toString()` wouldn't do.

Comment: By any chance is this request going crossdomain or is within the same domain?

Comment: What is this??? `function Searchwine(obj,str) {  {queryString: ""+str+""}, function(data){       `?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery improperly.

The proper syntax is (for POST)

```
$.post([URL], {
        var: value,
        var2: value
    }, function(data) {
        //callback goes here
    }
);
```

If you want to pass in the querystring as though it's a GET, just append it to the URL after a `?`.

E.G.:

```
"http://www.site.com/search/helper/autosuggest.php?" + str
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support cross domain ajax calls regardless if its getJSON or not. learned that the hard way... i ended up adding a local php file that used curl to get the results and return them to the script, its the only way to make ie work with cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do cross domain ajax requests, if the request url is in another domain, this fail, if the domain is the same, use a relative path:

```
jQuery.post("/search/helper/autosuggest.php"....
```

If you need Cross domain ajax request, you have to use jsonp (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

And if you are using post method, the queryString define a get vars, you need use data option

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/search/helper/autosuggest.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    sucess: function (data) {
         if (data) jQuery('#windatano').html(data);
    }
});
```

When data can be the object format:

```
var data = {
    a_var = 'value',
    other_var: 'other value'
};
```

Sorry my English